# IndexOutOfBoundsException when removing 0th element from Arraylist

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

I have used an ArrayList to store (as a queue) data that received through BLE. And I use the same ArrayList to pass data to the Bufferedwriter. Every time I called `.remove(0)` method to get the first element after verifying that ArrayList is nonempty by calling `.isempty()`  method. Please find the code sample below.

```
while (!ppgHighQueue.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        PPG ppg_record = ppgHighQueue.remove(0);
        if (ppg_record != null) {
            ppg_400Hz_record.write(ppg_record.toString());
            ppg_400Hz_record.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But rarely from this point following exception comes out and crash the app.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Are there any other feasible methods to store data rather going with ArrayList?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 this means you are calling the first element of an empty list. whether you use a map, array,  list or other sort of collection, the problem will always be similar

Comment: And this code is called from where? Because as is it is not thread-safe.

Comment: are you running this code in multiple threads ?

Comment: You tagged this with _multithreading_, so this is called from multiple threads? If so, it might be the case that two threads enter the loop, one removes an element and the second thread throws the exception since the list is empty.

Comment: @dhke this method runs in a separate thread. is that means do I need to synchronize the thread.

Comment: @Glains from the main thread I add element the ArrayList but only from the same thread I remove the element.

Comment: @Chandana You need to ensure that there's nothing happening to the queue between the calls to `.isEmpty()` and `.remove()`, e.g by synchronizing the method if it is the only remover. Or use [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and friends.

Comment: @dhke Thanks hope this will work

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not thread-safe. If `ppgHighQueue` is accessed from multiple threads it can be modified between `isEmpty()` and `remove(0)` calls.

You should consider synchronization of `ppgHighQueue` access.

Simplified example:

```
class SomeWorker {


    ArrayList ppgHighQueue;
    Object lock = new Object();

    void remover() {
        while (!ppgHighQueue.isEmpty()) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    if (ppgHighQueue.isEmpty()) continue; // this check after lock is needed
                    PPG ppg_record = ppgHighQueue.remove(0);
                    if (ppg_record != null) {
                        ppg_400Hz_record.write(ppg_record.toString());
                        ppg_400Hz_record.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void otherAccess() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (!ppgHighQueue.isEmpty()) {
                ppgHighQueue.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This 2nd `isEmpty` check ensures that your list is not empty after acquiring lock.